# How to set state in Carousel slider from a button click in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-component

I am using the react-bootstrap carousel component here: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/carousel/) and I am trying to set the 'defaultActiveIndex' prop (not mentioned in docs but it allows the carousel to keep autoplaying instead of using 'activeIndex' prop which prevents autoplay).

By setting this property through a button click, I want to set 'defaultActiveIndex', which should change the Carousel current position and then continue autoplaying afterwards.

I have this code in the component that holds the carousel state:

```
const [carouselIndex, setCarouselIndex] = useState(0);

function handleClick(e, param){
  setCarouselIndex(param);
  };
```

and the same component returns this:

```
<button onClick={(e) => handleClick(e, 3)}>Filter</button>
```

And the Carousel within the same component has the following props:

```
<Carousel
        className='carousel'
        variant='dark'
        fade={true}
        controls={true}
        slide={true}
        indicators={false}
        interval={1300}
        defaultActiveIndex={carouselIndex}
```

Currently I can see the handleClick function tracking the '3' coming from the button as param, but the 'setCarouselIndex' setter is not working and does not set 'carouselIndex' in the 'defaultActiveIndex' Carousel prop.

Full component code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Carousel from 'react-bootstrap/Carousel';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import './../App.css';

function Product(props) {
  
  const [carouselIndex, setCarouselIndex] = useState(0);

  function handleClick(e, param){
    setCarouselIndex(param);
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <Row>
          <Col>
          </Col>
          <Col>2</Col>
          <Col>3</Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
        <Col>
        </Col>
        <Col>
      <Carousel
        className='carousel'
        variant='dark'
        fade={true}
        controls={true}
        slide={true}
        indicators={false}
        interval={1300}
        defaultActiveIndex={carouselIndex}

      >
        
        {props.products.map(product =>

        <Carousel.Item
            key={product.product_id}
            className="carousel-item"
            
          >
            <div>
        <img
          className="d-block w-100"
          src={product.image_url}
          alt=""
          style={{
            borderRadius:"5px",
          }}
        />
          <div className="product-card-info"
          style={{
            borderRadius:"5px",
          }}
          >
          <p>Name: {product.product_name}</p>
          <p>Description: {product.description}</p>
          <p>Sizes(s): {product.size}</p>
          <p>{product.currency} {product.price}</p>
          <p>Delivery cost: {product.delivery_cost}</p>
          <p>{product.in_stock}</p>
          <p><a href={product.deeplink}>
            <span><i></i> Visit Product </span>
          </a>
          </p>
          <p><button onClick={(e) => handleClick(e, 3)}>Filter</button></p>
          </div>
          </div>
        </Carousel.Item>
      )}
    
    </Carousel>
    </Col>
    <Col>

    </Col>
    </Row>
    <Row>
  <Col>1</Col>
  <Col></Col>
</Row>
    </div>

    )
}

export default Product;
```

Any ideas or tips for how I could get this to work would be very much appreciated.

Thanks for your time all.

Comment: Try to put `useEffect` with `carouselIndex` as the dependency array and check if it changing (log the `carouselIndex` inside).

Comment: @BernhardJosephus It outputs: 'carouselIndex: 3' to the console in an infinite loop when I press the 'filter button', code used: useEffect(() => { console.log('carousel index: ', carouselIndex); }, [carouselIndex]);

Comment: Turns out that the `defaultActiveIndex` is only used for the first time the Carousel rendered based on this github issue https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/6263#issuecomment-1062121793